# Fast report expression use more than one filter conditions in delphi

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I am trying to filter data using expression in fast report. when i use one condition in the expression it is working properly.

```
<DSPatientProfileDetails."category"> = 'T-Short term'
```

But i want more than one condition just like sql where condition.
this is what i tried. but it gives error.

`<DSPatientProfileDetails."category"> = 'T-Short term' or` `<DSPatientProfileDetails."category"> = 'A-Antibiotics'`

Comment: Wild guess. Have you tried (<DSPatientProfileDetails."category"> = 'T-Short term') or (<DSPatientProfileDetails."category"> = 'A-Antibiotics')

Comment: @J.Pelttari It is worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm adding this as an answer.
You should put parenthesis around expressions as in delphi.

```
(<DSPatientProfileDetails."category"> = 'T-Short term') or (<DSPatientProfileDetails."category"> = 'A-Antibiotics')
```